# sql server rewrites my query incorrectly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a dirty data in input.
We are trying to cleanup dataset and then make some calculations on cleared data.

```
declare @t table (str varchar(10))
insert into @t select '12345' union all select 'ABCDE' union all select '111aa'

;with prep as
(
select *, cast(substring(str, 1, 3) as int) as str_int
from @t
where isnumeric(substring(str, 1, 3)) = 1
)

select * 
from prep
where 1=1
and case when str_int > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end = 'Y'
--and str_int > 0
```

Last 2 lines are doing the same thing. First one works, but if you uncomment second one it will crash with `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type int.`

Obviously, SQL Server is rewriting query mixing all the conditions together.
My guess it that it considers 'case' as a havy operation and performs it as a last step. That's why workaround with case works.

Is this behavior documented in any way? or is it a bug?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @beargle I can reproduce this in 2012.

Comment: So far I observe this behaviour in Express Editions 2012 and 2008, Enterprise 2008 (all that I have :) ). This small example has no external dependencies, you may try to run it on your server.

Comment: **even** if `ISNUMERIC` actually answered a question that it useful, you're only testing *one* character of input and then attempting to cast 3 characters to `int`. But it doesn't answer the question you think it does, so this is a doomed approach anyway.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is constructed example to demonstrate a problem. I agree that I could be more consistent dealing with substrings :). I will update question..

Comment: @vav . . . You should fix the code so the arguments to `substr()` are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue with SQL Server, and Microsoft does not consider it a bug although users do.  The difference between the two queries is the execution path.  One is doing the conversion before the filtering, the other after.

SQL Server reserves the right to re-order the processing.  The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) does specify the *logical* processing of clauses as:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

With (presumably but not explicitly documented here) CTEs being *logically* processed first.  What does *logically* processed mean?  Well, it doesn't mean that run-time errors are caught.  It really determines the scope of identifiers during the compile phase.

When SQL Server reads from a data source, it can add new variables in.  This is a convenient time to do this, because everything is in memory.  However, this might occur *before* the filtering, which is what is causing the error when it occurs.

The fix to this problem is to use a `case` statement.  So, the following CTE will usually work:

```
with prep as (
      select *, (case when isnumeric(substring(str, 1, 3)) = 1 and str not like '%.%'
                      then cast(substring(str, 1, 3) as int)
                 end) as str_int
      from @t
      where isnumeric(substring(str, 1, 3)) = 1
     )
```

Looks weird.  And I think Redmond thinks so too.  SQL Server 2012 introduced `try_convert()` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)) which returns `NULL` if the conversion fails.

It would also help if you could instruct SQL Server to materialize CTEs.  That would also solve the problem in this case.  You can vote on adding such an option to SQL Server [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables).

Comment: Of course, the use of `SUBSTRING` is a puzzler here since `'1bc'` is going to pass the `ISNUMERIC` test and then fail to be converted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . `1bc` fails `isnumeric()` (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8).  It is true that `1e6` will pass because it is exponential notation, and it might also fail.  So, I fixed the "will always work" part of the answer.

Comment: But what about `ISNUMERIC(substring('1bc',1,1))`, as per the OPs query?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . Your eyes are better than mine.  I fixed it in the answer and left a comment on the original question.